# find average value from CSV columns that contain a specific character

Tags: python, csv, sum, average

I am trying to get a simple python function which will read in a CSV file and find the average for come columns and rows. 
The function will examine the first row and for each column whose header
starts with the letter 'Q' it will calculate the average of values in
that column and then print it to the screen. Then for each row of the
data it will calculate the students average for all items in columns
that start with 'Q'. It will calulate this average normally and also
with the lowest quiz dropped. It will print out two values per student.

the CSV file contains grades for students and looks like this:

```
       hw1   hw2    Quiz3 hw4   Quiz2   Quiz1
john    87    98    76    67    90      56
marie   45    67    65    98    78      67
paul    54    64    93    28    83      98
fred    67    87    45    98    56      87
```

the code I have so far is this but I have no idea how to continue:

```
import csv


def practice():
newlist=[]
afile= input('enter file name')
a = open(afile, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(a, delimiter = ",")


for each in reader:
    newlist.append(each)
y=sum(int(x[2] for x in reader))
print (y)

filtered = []
total = 0

for i in range (0,len(newlist)):
    if 'Q' in [i][1]:
        filtered.append(newlist[i])
return filtered
```

Comment: You say you have a csv file, and your code specifies the delimiter as `","`, but your example text doesn't seem to have any commas.  Did you remove them for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the use of Pandas:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=' *')
>>> q_columns = [name for name in data.columns if name.startswith('Q')]

>>> reduced_data = data[q_columns].copy()
>>> reduced_data.mean()
Quiz3    69.75
Quiz2    76.75
Quiz1    77.00
dtype: float64

>>> reduced_data.mean(axis=1)
john     74.000000
marie    70.000000
paul     91.333333
fred     62.666667
dtype: float64

>>> import numpy as np
>>> for index, column in reduced_data.idxmin(axis=1).iteritems():
...     reduced_data.ix[index, column] = np.nan
>>> reduced_data.mean(axis=1)
john     83.0
marie    72.5
paul     95.5
fred     71.5
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have a nicer code if you change your `.csv` format. Then we can use [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) easily.

### grades.csv:

```
name,hw1,hw2,Quiz3,hw4,Quiz2,Quiz1
john,87,98,76,67,90,56
marie,45,67,65,98,78,67
paul,54,64,93,28,83,98
fred,67,87,45,98,56,87
```

### Code:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

result = defaultdict( list )
with open('grades.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) 
    for row in reader:
        for k in row:
            if k.startswith('Q'):
                result[ row['name'] ].append( int(row[k]) )
for name, lst in result.items():
    print name, np.mean( sorted(lst)[1:] )
```

### Output:

```
paul 95.5
john 83.0
marie 72.5
fred 71.5
```